# How to obtain audit logs for tags in AzureDevops

Tags: azure-devops, git-tag

I am trying to get some details on a deleted tag in a repository under AzureDevops.

It seems that tags are not audited (refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/audit/auditing-events?view=azure-devops#auditing)) and once deleted they do not appear in tag [either](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-tags?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#delete-a-tag-in-the-remote-repo). Is there some other way to get audit log for a tag?

Comment: a few things i read, audit should be turned on and it is on preview version.

Comment: From ur link: Auditing is only available for organizations backed by Azure Active Directory. For more information, see Connect your organization to Azure Active Directory.

Comment: Auditing is turned on for my org but audit logs for tags are not provided. Is there a way to get those?